# do you want to add a stub? SwiftWebViewProgress 0.3 in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I have build error like this with [SwiftWebViewProgress](https://github.com/mokumoku/SwiftWebViewProgress) 0.3 in Xcode 8.3.3

> Protocol requires function 'webViewProgress(_:updateProgress:)' with type '(WebViewProgress, Float) -> ()'; do you want to add a stub?

When I click Fix-it, Xcode write code as below, but I don't know hot to do next

```
class BrowserViewController: UIViewController,  UITextFieldDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, ActionViewControllerDelegate, WebViewProgressDelegate
{
    func webViewProgress(_ webViewProgress: WebViewProgress, updateProgress progress: Float) {
        <#code#>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution like this.

```
class BrowserViewController: UIViewController,  UITextFieldDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, ActionViewControllerDelegate, WebViewProgressDelegate
{
    func webViewProgress(_ webViewProgress: WebViewProgress, updateProgress progress: Float) {
        progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
    }
```